# Finding 2D rotation between two sets of points

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rotation

I am working on a project and I am stuck with one thing. I have two sets of points extracted from contours of the same object but rotated in 2D and I need to find the best rotation transformation (or just angle of rotation) between those points.

What I did is that I rescaled one of the contours so that I have two contours of the same size and also I made those two contours have the same center of mass. Then what I do is that I choose 3 random points from the first set of points and 3 points  of the second set of points (some kind of RANSAC in which I draw N times random points) and I need to find the rotation transformation around their center of mass of one set to the other one. I tried to use Kabsch algorithm but I'm not sure if I'm implementing it correctly because it is not working properly. Here is my code:

Here is my code of Kabsch:

```
// P,Q - sets of points of contours
cv::Mat Pt;
transpose(P, Pt); 

cv::Mat H = Pt * Q; 
cv::Mat Ht;
transpose(H,Ht); 
cv::Mat invH = H.inv(); 

cv::Mat HtH = Ht * H; 
cv::Mat sqrtH(HtH.size(), CV_32F); 

for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        sqrtH.at<float>(j, i) = sqrt(HtH.at<float>(j,i));
    }

// Final transform
cv::Mat R = sqrtH * invH;
```

I would like to at least get an angle of rotation between two sets of points. When I use my code I get strange results and transformation that are messing my sets of points up.

Comment: Hi, maybe this can help: https://nghiaho.com/?page_id=671

Comment: Great, the rotation works now. Thanks a lot!